balancing and imbalancing in supervised anomaly detection probelm
I am dealing with a supervised anomaly detection problem, where I have labels with 0 for normal and 1 for abnormal. The default distribution of the dataset is highly imbalanced with a ratio of 96:4 for normal and abnormal, respectively. Therefore, I applied random undersampling to decrease the ratio to 55:45 for normal and abnormal. Now, the accuracy is 98%, as shown below along with other metrics.
Now, the question is: Is this approach correct, or am I wrong? Here are the metrics scores I achieved:
Accuracy: 0.98467329
Precision: 0.98027553
Recall: 0.98755102
F1-score: 0.98389996
AUC: 0.98500429
Kappa: 0.97917268


What is the class ratio in your test set (or whatever set it is on which you calculated those performance metrics)?

70% for training, 15% for validation, and 15% for the test set, with class ratio 55:45 for normal and abnormal respectively.

You should not be artificially balancing the test set.

Does it mean we must keep the test set in its original form? Even, if the whole set is an anomaly or entirely normal?

Well, I'll put forth my answer from a research perspective and from my experience in anomaly detection
Truth is, it is hard to evaluate an anomaly detection model under supervised condition due to the fact that, it is hard to collect enough samples in many scenarios(including your case) and often it is cumbersome to interpret the model with typical evaluation metrics. Reason is that anomaly detection modeling comes under the subset of unsupervised machine learning. It’s unsupervised since there’s no predetermined target or “ground truth” that we can train our model to predict. Why I say so, data points that you labelled as anomaly can be a normal point in another context(we call it as contextual anomalies)
Random sampling is a handy technique for class imbalance, but that is not the only option available.
I'll suggest few of the new techniques you can use instead of this.

One-Class Classification - These algorithms you can apply for binary classification tasks with a severely skewed class distribution like the one you proposed here. One class support vector machine/ isolation forests are possible algorithms you can use instead of this. I don't really recommend binary classification for anomaly detection.
If possible use semi-supervised instead of total supervised - You can trick your approach by totally training your model with normal samples and conduct the inference with normal and abnormal samples. Often you can use an Autoencoder for this(There are a lot other than that, feel free to use any model that fits for your application). By doing so, you can see a drastic error increase for anomalies since it has never seen an anomaly. So, it is easy for you to evaluate rather than suffering with class imbalance.
Use advanced evaluations like AUC or pAUC for anomaly detection - I often suggest for any anomaly detection practitioner to use AUC/pAUC(https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.04754) over F1-score because it gives a scalar number that allows a natural ordering and is independent on a threshold, which allows to postpone the choice. You don't need of other metrics when having them because you can comment entirely about your model by using these metrics . It better explains scenarios like false alarms and interprets your results even better. Have a look on those aspects too.
Synthetic over-sampling: SMOTE
Synthetic minority oversampling technique, also termed as SMOTE, is a clever way to perform over-sampling over the minority class to avoid overfitting(unlike random over-sampling that has overfitting problems)

Hope you grasp my viewpoint. Anyway, It's hard to give a direct right answer for your question by looking at the numbers. I'm helping you to remodel your answer with better explanations.

I am using a Transformer-based neural network to evaluate the Encoder layer for classification. I chose the HAI dataset, specifically version 23.5, which is available in a supervised format.
Even though the model shows high accuracy, I am unsure if I am on the right path logically. Many blogs and articles suggest using the construction error-based method with a threshold (an unsupervised method).
Am I proceeding correctly?

I also recommend you to go with unsupervised, if you go ahead with supervised, model will not generalized to normal samples and sometimes it will not capture anomlies well.
